# Angular 4 with TypeScript: passing parameters by reference

Tags: angular, typescript, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm just starting to develop a web application with angular 4 with TypeScript language.
My question is: if I initialize a string variable with the value of a data field in my class, it looks like the value is passed for copy and not for reference.

Is there a way to pass the parameter for reference?

Example:

```
export class MyObject {
   string1: string;
   string2: string;
}

export class MyClass {
   myString: string;
   object: MyObject;
   array[]: MyObject[];

   constructor() {
      this.array = [{
       string1: this.myString;
       string2: this.myString;
      }];
   }

}
```

If I tried to change the value of field `this.myString` and then use string interpolation in my HTML template

```
{{myString}}

{{array[0].string1}} {{array[0].string2}}
```

the only value that has changed is `myString`, while the other two values ​​remained the same as `myString`'s first value. This is because it seems that the passage of the parameters has been done for value and not by reference.

Sorry if the question is trivial, but I'm learning TypeScript right now

Comment: Strings are immutable in JS/TS.

Comment: The code you provided confuses me. It seems like you are using the MyClass with @Component

Comment: As @jonrsharpe mentioned, strings are immutable. If you want to use the new value of `this.myString` to other parts of your template, why not just remove the `array` and use the `this.myString` directly to the other parts of your template if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should to change value from array like

```
<input [(ngModel)]="array[0].string1">
```

In ur array new instances of myString;

Answer (score 0):

This is generally the way variables work in Javascript (also most other modern programming languages, Java, C#, etc). A common way to pass by reference is to create an additional object that holds the string and assign the reference to that object anywhere you need it.

For example:

```
export interface MyObject {
   string1: Ref;
   string2: Ref;
}
export interface Ref {
    value: string
}
export class MyClass {
   myString: Ref;
   array: MyObject[];

   constructor() {
      this.myString = { value: "old Vlaue"};
      this.array = [{
       string1: this.myString,
       string2: this.myString
      }];
      this.myString.value = "New Value"
   }
}
```

When you bind you then use:

```
{{myString.value}}

{{array[0].string1.value}} {{array[0].string2.value}}
```

Comment: If I use the wrapper object String as an alternative to the primitive type string, everything would work well ?

Comment: If you use `prop.value` everywhere you need the string value, I expect it should. But you should test and see.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: If you have `var myObject = { string1: { value: 'x' }, string2: { value:'y' } }` then var `d = myObject.string1 + myObject.string2` will not work for example. You would  need to use `d = myObject.string1.value + myObject.string2.value`. Generally anywhere you need the value, you need to use `prop.value` not just `prop`